# Postgres json select not ignoring quotes

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table and setup

```
create table test (
  id serial primary key,
  name text not null,
  meta json
);

insert into test (name, meta) values ('demo1', '{"name" : "Hello"}')
```

However, when I run this query, this is the result

```
select * from test;
 id | name  |        meta
----+-------+--------------------
  1 | demo1 | {"name" : "Hello"}
(1 row)
```

but

```
select * from test where meta->'name' = 'Hello';
ERROR:  operator does not exist: json = unknown
LINE 1: select * from test where meta->'name' = 'Hello';
                                              ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

-

```
select * from test where cast(meta->'name' as text) = 'Hello';
 id | name | meta
----+------+------
(0 rows)
```

and this works

```
select * from test where cast(meta->'name' as text) = '"Hello"';
 id | name  |        meta
----+-------+--------------------
  1 | demo1 | {"name" : "Hello"}
(1 row)
```

Can anyone tell me what the relevance of this quote is and why it's not doing a simple string search/comparison? Alternatively, does this have something to do with the casting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the `->` gets a field not a value, so you need to add the cast to say to postgresql which data type you are after.

So to run your query like you want you need to use the `->>` which gets the json element as text see it here on the docs [JSON Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html)

So your query should looks like:

```
select *
  from test 
 where meta->>'name' = 'Hello';
```

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bf866/8